# Query on comprehensive ranking system - Express Entry

Tags: immigration, canada, resident-permit, ielts, language-test

I have two IELTS score with two attempts.

```
 ability         Listening       Reading    Writing    Speaking

IELTS Test 1       6.5             5.5        6.5         7.0

IELTS Test2        6.0             6.5        6.0         6.0
```

As per this [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp),  I would like to understand, which is the best score that i can apply for  Express entry.

Because am still not clear, if IELTS score - 6 per ability is the requirement anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but it's not on the page that you linked to. To score points on abilities in the first or second official languages (OL) (English or French), you have to score the equivalent of [Canadian Language Board 7 or greater](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/factor-language.asp) (CLB 7). For the IELTS, that's approximately a 6 or better in any of the 4 ability areas. Because you have a 5.5 in Reading on your first test, it doesn't count, but the 7.0 in Speaking gives you a CLB 9 and 6 points. Unfortunately, that's not enough to counteract the Reading score so you end with a total of 15 points. You score more points using Test2: 17 points.

The actual breakdown of the point equivalencies is [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-testing.asp):

```
First official language (Maximum 24 points)

CLB Level     Speaking    Listening    Reading    Writing      Points per ability
7                 6.0     6.0 – 7.0      6.0        6.0             4 
8                 6.5        7.5         6.5        6.5             5 
9 and above   7.0 – 9.0   8.0 – 9.0    7.0 – 9.0  7.0 – 9.0         6
```

If you also spoke French as designated it as your first OL, then you would only need to meet CLB 5, and the IELTS values could be 5 or greater, but you max out points at 16 because you can only score 4 points per ability.

Comment: when I say, English is not my first language, It means, my IELTS score sheet says First language is `Hindi`

Comment: i felt this is the right [link](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/express-entry/grid-crs.asp), where it says:`Official languages proficiency - second official language`. am i wrong?

Comment: Canada has two official languages: English and French. I am pretty sure that that's what they're referring to. I think you can choose either as your "first" language (aka whichever one you have better abilities in) but can also score a few extra points if you know the second OL.

Comment: what does exactly "first official language" and "second official language" mean?

Comment: If I understand correctly, Canada wants you to have some language abilities in either English or French before you emigrate. In fact, Quebec requires some French ability. So you can designate either English or French as your "first" foreign language and other (if you know both) as your "second" foreign language. For your "second" foreign language, you are allowed to score lower (CLB 5).