# Express entry for canada

Tags: immigration, canada, ielts, express-entry

My IELTS score is as under

1. Listening : 8.5
2. Reading : 6.5
3. Speaking : 7.0
4. Writing  : 7.0

Am i eligible for applying for the express entry program for immigration to canada

Comment: See http://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/4390/query-on-comprehensive-ranking-system-express-entry

Answer (score 3):

Being eligible to apply for Express Entry depends not only on your language test results, but also on a number of other factors. Please use the Come to Canada Tool provided by CIC to check if you are eligible for Express Entry:
http://www.cic.gc.ca/ctc-vac/cometocanada.asp

CIC also has a tool to compute how many CRS points you will get for your language test results:
http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/immigrate/skilled/language-tool.asp